# why is my for loop ignoring an item?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, dictionary

I am a complete beginner and recently learning for to use python
I have a problem with my code. I am trying to count the number of items if the list addedList and then add it to the value in the dictionary if the key for that value exists if not I create a new key and update the count. 
The the problem is that in a list where by there is more than  one item, this can lead to one item been  counted more than once. 
My strategy was to use the remove method to remove the item fromn the list. 
I believed that this will prevent the item from being counted more than once.

However, when I run the code it. I get an error: IndexEror:  index out of range

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    lst = list(addedItems)
    for item in range(0, len(addedItems)-1):
        count = lst.count(lst[item])
        if addedItems[item] in inventory:
            inventory[lst[item]] += count
            if count > 1:
                for i in range(0, count):
                    word = lst[item]
                    addedItems.remove(word)
        else:
            inventory.setdefault(lst[item], count)   
inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
displayInventory(inv)
```

I found out that after I remove all the item gold coin. I am successfullly able to add 'dagger' to the dictionary but  not 'ruby'.

I want someone to please explain
Why the for loop fail to ierate to 'ruby'?
How do i fix it?

I hope the community understand  what I am saying,as I tried my best to break down my problem

thank you for helping me.

Comment: i am getting another error `SyntaxError: bad input ('lst')`, you sure this is the code?

Comment: Here's a golden rule: Don't modify the thing you are looping over inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with your iteration. Generally, doing a `for i in range(...)` is not the best option in python, unless you really do need the index, rather than just the item.

In your case, it actually breaks your code, however. Your for loop is from 0 to the second to last (more on this later) index of addedItems *when the loop started*. But when you remove items from addedItems, it gets shorter! Thus, at some point later, your loop will try to access an index that's not there. This is why you get the indexError with 'gold coin'.

Why doesn't 'ruby' work? Because `range` doesn't include the last number: you would need to use `range(0,len(addedItems))` instead. Thus with your code, you only go up to the second to last value.

The end result of this is that it is a much better idea to just iterate through items. To deal with the item potentially not existing in the dictionary, you can just use the `get` method with a default value of 0:

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for item in addedItems:
        inventory[item] = inventory.get(item,0)+1
inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
print inv
```

Note too that your function `addToInventory` modifies the (mutable = modifiable) inventory that's passed into it, and doesn't return anything, thus returning `None`. Thus `inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)` actually modifies `inv` when `addToInventory` runs, and then *sets `inv` to `None`*, the return value of the function! So you'll want to use just `addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of checking counts and using `setdefault`, simply iterate through the list of loot and add each item to the appropriate entry when possible, creating a new entry when necessary:

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for item in addedItems:
        if item in inventory:
            inventory[item] += 1
        else:
            inventory[item] = 1
```

There are other ways to do this, with `get`, `setdefault`, `collections.defaultdict`, and/or `collections.Counter`, but if you're a complete beginner the above method will probably be easiest to follow.

Note that there's no need to rebind `inv = ...`, as the function mutates `inv` directly. Call it without saving a reference:

```
addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
```

Comment: You have to return `inventory`, otherwise nothing changes.

Comment: @Rahn - It should be neither returned nor rebound. I'll add a note to that effect.

Comment: you are right, then you could just do `addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)` rather than `inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)`